# How to set Background Color for React-Select Option component when hovering with Arrow Keys

Tags: css, reactjs, select, hover, react-select

I'm able to set the background color for an Option (React-Select) upon a :hover from the mouse (as shown in the code below)... What I can't figure out is how to set the background color for an Option when I'm using the Arrow Keys on my keyboard. The down/up Keys work to select an Option but I can't get it's background color to change while I'm positioned over the Option with the arrow Keys (up/down)

```
<Select
    placeholder="Month"
    styles={{
       option: (base) => ({
           ...base,
           cursor: "pointer",
           background: "white",   // this was the mistake (I needed to remove this)
           ":hover": {
              backgroundColor: "rgb(200, 200, 200)",
            },
     }}
/>
```

Comment: Have you tried using state to set an 'active' id tag? Or say you're mapping these values, you could use a value in the map to set individual id's which you could target in css.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const customStyles = {
    option: (base, { data, isDisabled, isFocused, isSelected }) => {
    return {
      ...base,
      backgroundColor: isFocused ? "red" : "blue",
    };
  }
};

const options = [
  { value: "aaa", label: "aaa" },
  { value: "bb", label: "bb" },
  { value: "cc", label: "cc" }
];

 <Select
    label="Single select"
    options={options}
    styles={customStyles}
  />
```

please use isFocused instead. hope it can help

Comment: THank you for hte response! I actually realized that React-Select already provides the the hover and isFocused features by default. The issue is I had the background for Option set to white so nothing would change